# Why doesn't Torque of masses on a pulley depend on the friction between the rob and the pulley according to a question in the physics 1 book

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, torque

[image]
[image]

What I don't understand about this question is: why is the torque of the masses on the pulley equals the weight of each mass times the  radius. I thought that the torque on the pulley from the masses depends also on the friction between the rob and the pulley so why they depended only on the weight and the radius. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "no slip". That means more than enough friction, so you can treat the string as if were a chain draped over a sprocket.

They're trying to simplify the problem for you.